# Comparison Method violates its general contract. Simple comparison

Tags: java, swing, comparison, contract

I'm doing a card game in swing (java)

The user has to wait his turn, take a card, and press confirm. When it's not his turn, he can't take any card.

It starts this way:

```
this.cardTaken = false;
board.canTakeCards(!cardTaken);
```

Then in board class it comes the next action:

```
public void canTakeCards(boolean can) {
        if (can) {
            this.btnConfirm.setEnabled(false);
            this.pnlCards.setCanTake(true);

        } else {
            this.btnConfirm.setEnabled(true);
            this.pnlCards.setCanTake(false);
        }
```

(the `else` happens when the user takes a card).

So. I got the `Comparison method violates its general contract` at line `board.canTakeCards(!cardTaken);`

That only happened one time and I "tested" my game for about 8 times. I'm really confused and afraid about this.

One of my theories is that I call this function from 2 differents parts of the code at the same execution time, and it receives a `true` and `false` at the same time. But I revised my code and i think that's imposible.

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to post some relevant code like where do you call `board.canTakeCards(!cardTaken);` .

Comment: Your code does not show any comparison. Can you give us the inner details of `canTakeCards`? Which custom objects are involved there?

Comment: You "got" the message? Who gave it to you? IDE? Compiler? Runtime? Is it an Exception?

Comment: You need fewer theories and more data.

Comment: I didnt remember exactly because it happened 2 days ago. I think it was an Exception. `this.pnlCards.setCanTake` only calls this on pnlCards:
`public void setCanTake(boolean b){
  this.canTake= b;
 }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message text is included in an exception thrown from Java 7 sorted collections, indicating that the object in question has an inconsistent implementation of `compareTo`, which basically means it is not imposing a total ordering on the objects. Prior to Java 7 this was silently ignored. Revise your `Comparable` classes.

Comment: Those are just simple booleans. I dont know what are you trying to say me. I dont have any comparable class in all my game. Sorry for my newbie knowledge.

Comment: After carefully reading your question I concluded that you are getting this error at runtime, which means it is an exception. There must be some code involved which throws the exception, then. It is impossible to get it with just the code you have posted.

Comment: Yes, i got this error at runtime. Sorry if i didnt mention that. (still noob). About posting more code... i have thousand and thousand of lines and i cant atm (my function and variables names are in Catalan, so i have to translate them to make it more clear for you guys). Anyway, is it possible that happens what i mentioned before? **One of my theories is that I call this function from 2 differents parts of the code at the same execution time, and it receives a true and false at the same time**

Comment: The identifiers will not be a major impediment to understanding code. It is the logic that counts. You can't possibly get an exception without your execution entering a Java class which contains the line `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparison method violates its general contract")`. So your first goal must be to see how that line is reached. This is a trivial task: just examine the stack trace of your exception. If you have a `catch` somewhere which doesn't print the stacktrace, then correct that first.